# Persist cache with apollo-boost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, graphql, react-apollo

I've got a quick question.

How can we persist the cache using apollo-boost lib?

I am not sure how to implement `apollo-cache-persist` with the following config.

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:8080/_/service/com.suppliers/graphql',
  clientState: {
    defaults: {
      networkStatus: {
        __typename: 'NetworkStatus',
        isConnected: false,
      },
    },
    resolvers: {
      Query: {},
      Mutation: {
        updateNetworkStatus: (_, { isConnected }, { cache }) => {
          cache.writeData({
            data: {
              networkStatus: {
                __typename: 'NetworkStatus',
                isConnected,
              },
            },
          })
          return null
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Set up the cache as per the cache-persist example [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-cache-persist#web):

Then, pass it as a custom cache in the boost configuration, as shown in the cache configuration section [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/get-started.html#configuration):

For example:

```
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { persistCache } from 'apollo-cache-persist';

const cache = new InMemoryCache({...});

persistCache({
  cache,
  storage: window.localStorage,
});

import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "https://48p1r2roz4.sse.codesandbox.io",
  cache: cache
});
```